# Error: Module `css` does not provide a view engine

Tags: css, express, gulp

`Error: Module "css" does not provide a view engine.` from concatenating `gulp.src` params.

NO ERROR:

```
const css = [
  'src/scss/main.scss',
];
```

ERROR WITH THIS:

```
const css = [
  'src/assets/scss/reset.scss',
  'src/assets/scss/styles.scss',
  'src/scss/main.scss',
];
```

Here's my gulp setup:

```
// Compile Sass with source maps
gulp.task('sass-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src(css)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass().on('error', logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer(CONFIG))
      .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(css)
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer(CONFIG))
      .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/css'));
});
```

Comment: I don't think that is a gulp error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848773/error-module-html-does-not-provide-a-view-engine-express Are you using express?

Comment: yeah i am, it's a css file though, so not sure why it would be rendered as a view